# How restrict only one pull request at a time in TFS git?

Tags: git, tfs, request, pull

I am setting up a Development process with CI implemented. I would like to restrict number of pull request at any point it time to be one. Is that possible in TFS git?

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible. It is always possible to submit multipel pull requests.